# React Native iOS pod setup has duplicate target issue

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I'm building an app with React Native and I have to add pod dependencies to my project. I followed a [tutorial](https://shift.infinite.red/beginner-s-guide-to-using-cocoapods-with-react-native-46cb4d372995) on how to init a pod with a brand new react-native init project. This is the content of my Podfile:

```
target 'MyProject' do

  target 'MyProject-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

  target 'MyProjectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end

target 'MyProject-tvOS' do

  target 'MyProject-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end
```

Then I run `pod install`, and I get this error:

> The target `MyProject-tvOSTests` is declared twice.

I think it's an issue with the react-native init but I don't know how to correct it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove the second target thats it!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `MyProject-tvOSTests` target is duplicated. Remove the first instance of it.

```
target 'MyProject' do

  target 'MyProjectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end

target 'MyProject-tvOS' do

  target 'MyProject-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end
```

Comment: Yep that worked (and it was rather easy when I think about it... Being a beginner is always funny ahah) Thanks man, I accept your answer !